# Determine the end of a cyclic workflow in spring integration (inbound-channel => service-activator)

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

We have the following simple int-jpa based workflow:

[inbound-channel-adapter] -> [service-activator]

The config is like this:

```
<int:channel id="inChannel">  <int:queue/> </int:channel>
<int:channel id="outChannel"> <int:queue/> </int:channel>
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="inChannelAdapter"  channel="inChannel"
     jpa-query="SOME_COMPLEX_POLLING_QUERY"
     max-results="2">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="2" fixed-rate="20" >
        <int:advice-chain synchronization-factory="txSyncFactory"   >
            <tx:advice transaction-manager="transactionManager" >
                <tx:attributes>
                    <tx:method name="*" timeout="30000" />
                </tx:attributes>
            </tx:advice>
            <int:ref bean="pollerAdvice"/>
        </int:advice-chain>
    </int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inChannel" ref="myActivator"
 method="pollEntry" output-channel="outChannel" />

<bean id="myActivator" class="com.company.myActivator" />    
<bean id="pollerAdvice" class="com.company.myPollerAdvice" />
```

The entry point for processing is a constantly growing table against which the `SOME_COMPLEX_POLLING_QUERY` is run. The current flow is :

1. *[Thread-1]* The `SOME_COMPLEX_POLLING_QUERY` will only return entries that has `busy` set to `false` (we set `busy` to `true` as soon as polling is done using `txSyncFactory`)
2. *[Thread-2]* These entries will pass through the `myActivator` where it might take anywhere from 1 min to 30 mins.
3. *[Thread-2]* Once the processing is done, we set back the `busy` from `true` to `false`

**Problem**: We need to trigger a notification even when the processing of all the entries that were present in the table is done.

**Approach tried**: We used the `afterReturning` of `pollerAdvice` to find out if the `SOME_COMPLEX_POLLING_QUERY` returned any results or not. However this method will start returning "No Entries" way before the `Thread-2` is done processing all the entries.

Note:

- The same entries will be processes again after 24hrs. But this time it will have more entries.
- We are not using `outbound-channel-adapter`, since we dont have any requirement for it. However, we are open to use it, if that is a part of the solution proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that will work for you, but since you still need to wait with the notification until `Thread-2`, I would suggest to have some `AtomicBoolean` bean. In the mentioned `afterReturning()`, when there is no data polled from the DB, you just change the state of the `AtomicBoolean` to `true`. When the `Thread-2` finishes its work, it can call `<filter>` to check the state of the `AtomicBoolean` and then really perform an `<int-event:outbound-channel-adapter>` to emit a notification event.

So, the final decision to emit event or not is definitely done from the `Thread-2`, not polling channel adapter.

Comment: Thanks Artem. But, am not sure how will we know when the **`Thread-2` finishes its work**?

Comment: Well, isn't that what you get in the `outChannel`? And you say yourself: `Once the processing is done`. So, looks like you know what's going on

Comment: And one more note: if there are polled messages from the DB you need to reset that `AtomicBoolean` flag to `false` with the meaning "not finished" for the `Thread-2`

Comment: Well, right now I am not using the `outChannel` as mentioned in the note. With `Once the processing is done` i meant in the `myActivator` itself, we make a call to DB and set the flag to `false`.